# Graph API - Cover picture sizes

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'd like to know wether there is a way to get `cover picture` from `Facebook` in different sizes.

For instance https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/18700052_1429322240461244_4107881063444434571_n.jpg?oh=58da853e5b56da48a3d0a151304683af&oe=599C2573"

I tries to change `_n` but it does not work

Comment: Get the `images` field of the cover photo object ...

Comment: I don't see anything related with the size https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/cover-photo/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1429322240461244%3Ffields%3Dimages%2Cwidth%2Cheight&version=v2.9